# How to zoom mapView and setCenterCoordinate at the same time?

Tags: swift, geolocation, mapkit, core-location

I have a mapView and I use didUpdateLocations to show location user, but I also use setCenterCoordinate to show the pin blue circle predeterminate for show the location in left of the mapView. But if I use setCenterCoordinate the map not does zoom...

```
 churchLocation.longitude += self.mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta * 0.15;

    churchLocation.latitude += self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta * 0.10;

 self.mapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)
    self.mapView.setCenterCoordinate(churchLocation, animated: true)
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`setRegion` and `setCenterCoordinate` are going to work against each other. The view will be looking at the center of `theRegion`, then you're trying to move it to look at `churchLocation`.

If you want to set both the zoom level and the you should use the `churchLocation` and calculate a region around it and then call `setRegion` with that.